# Stop video playing at the end of the movie XNA

Tags: c#, xna, movie, video-player

I'm playing a .wmv movie in XNA. I have no problem in playing it but I can't seem to detect if the movie reach its end and stop the movie from playing.

Here's how I do it:

```
Video video;
VideoPlayer player;
```

On Update method:

```
//Playing the movie
        #region
        if (playIntroMovie == true)
        {
            player.Play(video);
            player.Volume = 1;
            if (player.State == MediaState.Stopped)
            {
                player.Stop();
                videoTexture = null;
                playIntroMovie = false;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

On draw method:

```
if (player.State != MediaState.Stopped)
            videoTexture = player.GetTexture();
        if (videoTexture != null)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(videoTexture, fullScreenRec, Color.White);
        }
```

I know that if the moview has ended, its state will return to MediaState.Stopped so I'm trying to stop it and set its texture to null. But the movie loops and plays again. I included player.isLooped = false; but the movie still loops. Any ideas on what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because in your Update() loop, you are calling player.Play() constantly (playIntroMovie will always be true until the MediaState hits Stopped for the first time).

A better way to handle your Update() loop logic would be something like this:

```
if (playIntroMovie == true)
{
    player.Play(video);
    playIntroMovie = false;
    player.Volume = 1;
}

if (player.State == MediaState.Stopped)
{
   player.Stop();
   videoTexture = null;
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this on my update method(), but the way I see it and based from the output. The playIntroMovie will always be false. Hence, the player would not play. I tried moving the playintroMovie = false inside the checking of the player state. In result, the video still loops. :(

Comment: I finally able to stop the video by using a different approach. I put a delay based on the length of the video and after the delay, I will stop the video. I don't know why player.State == MediaState.Stopped won't work. Thanks anyway!